# Refresh SignalR telerik grid

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, signalr, kendo-grid

I have a grid bind to SignalR hub on what's down

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyDownloader.Core.ViewModel.DownloaderViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.LocalFile);
        columns.Bound(c => c.FileSize);
        columns.Bound(c => c.StatusMessage);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Progress);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Left);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Rate);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDateTime);
        columns.Bound(c => c.State);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ResourceLocation);
        columns.Command(c => c.Destroy());

    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;margin-bottom:20px;" })
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .SignalR()
    .AutoSync(true)
    .Events(events => events.Push("onPush"))
    .Sort(s => s.Add("FileSize").Descending())
    .Transport(tr => tr
        .Promise("hubStart")
        .Hub("hub")
        .Client(c => c
            .Read("read")
            .Create("create")
            .Update("update")
            .Destroy("destroy"))
        .Server(s => s
            .Read("read")
            .Create("create")
            .Update("update")
            .Destroy("destroy"))).Schema(schema => schema
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id("FileSize");
        }))
    ))
```

I want to update all client when an object added to database (Downloader Table)
I call `read()` client method out side the hub like this

```
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hubs.DownloadrHub>();
        context.Clients.All.read();
```

but `read()` method not raised and grid not refresh and Data not update

How can update all client grid out of the Hub?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't call the read method on the client. You call the create, update or delete method. Depending on the action performed. The grid handles it automagically.

E.g. Clients.All.update(new { Data = whateveryourdatais );

Have a look at the telerik [examples](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-demos-service/blob/master/signalr-hubs/signalr-for-aspnet-core/Hubs/ProductHub.cs).